# Proof of |x · y| = |x| · |y| using axioms of real numbers

Tags: calculus, real-numbers, proof-explanation, axioms

I'm trying to prove |x · y| = |x| · |y| using only the axioms of real numbers. I'm using the definition of the modulus function to be below. I thought I should start by distinguishing four cases like (x>0,y>0),(x<0,y<0),(y or x is equal to zero) and (y>0,x<0). Is this right?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qHgQ.gif)

Comment: distinguish possible cases.

Comment: I would have done it by looking at cases, but I do like the suggestion of @dxiv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint for an alternative proof without using cases.

- Prove that $\;\;|a|^2=a^2$
- Prove that $\;\;|a|=|b| \;\; \iff \;\; a^2=b^2$
- Prove that $\;\;(x \cdot y)^2 = x^2 \cdot y^2$
- Deduce from the above that $\;\;|x \cdot y|=|x| \cdot |y|$

Comment: I believe in the sufficiency direction of the second bullet point, you might want to use $|b|=|-b|$ which is still easy to establish.

Comment: @RobertWolfe Indeed, it's equivalent to $|a|=|b| \iff a = \pm b\,$.